# replacing file names that contain ( and )

Tags: regex, bash

I have multiple files with this format

```
a file (www.something.com)
```

and I want to remove the `(www.something.com)` recursively. I expect that

```
rename 's/\(*\)//' a\ file\ \(www.something.com\)
```

should do the job but it doesn't! why? Then I want to do that recursively like this

```
find . -name '*\(*\)' -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/\(*\)/}' {} \;
```

Comment: Belongs to Unix & Linux stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
s='a file (www.something.com)'
touch "$s"
ls "a file"*
a file (www.something.com)

# renane command
rename 's/ [^ ]*$//' "$s"

ls "a file"*
a file
```

Make it **recursive** using find:

```
find . -name '*\(*\)' -exec rename 's/ [^ ]*$//' '{}' \;
```

OR else **without using rename**:

```
find . -name '*\(*\)' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(sed "s/ [^ ]*$//"<<<"$1")"' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: I have pasted results above in my answer so that you can see it. Was your input file named exactly as `a file (www.something.com)` OR something else?

Comment: @mahmood: Even this rename works fine: `rename 's/ [^ ]*$//' a\ file\ \(www.something.com\)`

Comment: Are you using BASH or something else? I will dig in to that

Comment: If you want I can post a solution without use of `rename`

Comment: Glad to know it worked. As you will notice I am using exact same regex I used for `rename`. May be your `rename` was old version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to say:

```
rename 's/\(.*\)//' filename
```

You need to add `.` before `*`.